# IOS GameCenter SandBox mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I plan to update my current game on the app store and integrate GameCenter within. I have completed it and tested it on a device. Now on the device whenever I login, its the sandbox state. Even if I am logged in from GameCenter the still asks me to sign in on the sandbox state. How do I test on the non sandbox version. I a bit confused. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the non-sandbox version until it is approved and published by Apple.
If it works fine in sandbox mode, then it should work fine when Apple switches it to non-sandbox.

Comment: One question though. The high score record gets posted. But when I sign in under a different gamecenter account. It still only shows one record, not the score for the previous account. I am testing on the same device. Any thoughts?

Comment: When I did some GC work, I found the sandbox not to be very quick. I had 3 accounts and couldn't figure out why scores weren't visible. The next day they all showed up.

Comment: I see. so right now on whichever account im using for gamecenter, the high score is correct. Now if I look at the leaderboard tomorrow from another account, will all the records be up?

Comment: Yes, maybe after some time you will see all other sandbox accounts too. At least that was my experience.

Comment: Thank You very much Darren. Id love to voteup but my rep is under 15. So *Vote Up*.

Answer (score 1):

The sandbox is meant for testing your app, so you won't destroy the normal GC servers.
To summarize- your final app will work on the regular GC servers, while the test is on sandbox. Apple rules.

Comment: One question though. The high score record gets posted. But when I sign in under a different gamecenter account. It still only shows one record, not the score for the previous account. I am testing on the same device. Any thoughts?